# Automatically add flags to command

Tags: git, git-log, git-config

I am a frequent user of `git log -G[string]`, and I almost always find myself using `--all` and `--no-textconv` with it.

Can I somehow tell `git` to use those two options by default when calling `git log -G[string]`? Part of the problem is that `-G` expects its input with no space.

Comment: Did you consider having a simple alias?

Comment: He might be using cmd.exe. Aliases work only on linux or Git Bash.

Comment: @sashoalm the git CLI itself also has aliases.

Comment: How do you do it in this case though ? I will specify what I attempted and the message I got. Also, ideally, I would like `git` to naturally add those flags when using `git log -G` - if that is possible.

Comment: And no, I am using Git Bash and know how to write aliases - at least basic ones.

Comment: (Also, it's `--no-textconv`, not `--no-text-conv`)

Comment: For those wondering, it's not possible to override git commands to always add flags. So a new alias is the only option.

Answer (score 1):

The git alias route could look like

```
git config --global alias.lg '!f() { git log --no-textconv --all -G"$1"; }; f'

# then you'd do
git lg "regexp here"
```

Comment: Ah very good. Why the quotes, both in the function and when calling the alias ?

Comment: Yes, needed for both.

Comment: Understood. WHY though ?

Comment: The quote consumption logic in bash + git context is well above my humble knowledge, I'd refer you to the bash experts.

Comment: Okay, then let me ask a sub-par question : how do you know they are needed in this specific situation then ? And how does that generalize ? This info will come in handy for some other aliases I may have/later come up with.

Comment: By experience, trial and error, as low tech as it sounds.

Answer (score 0):

Use `[alias]` in the `~/.gitconfig`.

```
[alias]
    logp = "!f() { git log -p $1; }; f"
```

Then `git logp`.